# how to reload specific div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have `countdown` in my `container` div but when I tried to reload that specific `container` its reload perfectly but my `countdown` didn't showed up and also button got disabled..

```js
function refreshDiv() {
  $('.container').load(window.location.href + " .container >*");
}
```

javascript

```
var spn = document.getElementById("count");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

var count = 2; // Set count
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

(function countDown() {
  // Display counter and start counting down
  spn.textContent = count;

  // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
  if (count !== 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    count--; // decrease the timer
  } else {
    // Enable the button
    btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}());
```

this is html

```html
<div class="container">

    <h2>choose product </h2>
    <input type="file" name="inpFile" id="inpFile">

    <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
      <img src="" alt="Image Preview" id="zoom" class="image- 
           preview__image">
      <span class="image-preview__default-text">choose image</span>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <h4 id="title">here</h4>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="main-controls">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="btnCounter" disabled>File <span id="count"></span></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item" onclick="refreshDiv();">Save</button>
```

Comment: @ 
Andreas
i am new here

Comment: If you haven't received any answers, then the reason is most likely you haven't included enough information regarding the problem or made a reproducible example.

Comment: @Andreas
 I updated title please help to solve my question

Comment: The `.load()` call overwrites the content of `#container3` which kills the button you got with `.getElementById()`. Move the `.getElementById()` calls into the `countDown()` function

Comment: @ 
Andreas
sir I did but same problem showing

Comment: @Andreas
 I edited my question can you please look up

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things going on in there that don't make much sense. Most of that is more mistaken terminology than mistaken code though.

Your `countDown` function does 3 things (which is good),

- it bumps the counter to the next value,
- updates the counterdisplay, and
- it restarts itself (after a timeout)

(again, good); but the **order it does those things in** is totally weird though: you update the visual display, before you modify the very value that the display shows. In other words, you go out of your way have an inaccurate display.

---

"maybe console is work properly." no idea what that means or what it is even in relation to.

---

`refreshDiv()` & "..**when i refresh** the whole page but when i **refresh #container3**.."

You don't *refresh* `<div>`s, you update them.
The fact that you're using the wrong language for that concept has led
you to think that something completely unrelated (*refreshing* the browser) is somehow similar or related.

---

`<div class="container2" id="container3">` cant help but wonder what the logic behind a `#container3` with a `.container2` class is; but it won't really cause problems until the person who inherits that code has to pay off his psychiatrist.

---

The easiest fix is likely something like:

```
var spn = document.getElementById("count");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

var count = 3; // Set counter (+ add 1 second)
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

(function countDown() {
    // decrease the counter (but never below zero)
    count = ( --count > 0 ? count : 0 );

    if (count > 0) {
        // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
        timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    } else {
        // Enable the button
        btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }

    // Display counter
    spn.textContent = count;
}());
```

Comment: sir thank you for your replay but still showing same problem

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more clear about what that means. What do you want/expect to happen, and what is happening instead ?

Comment: see when I refresh the whole page my countdown timer work perfectly when I refresh only particular div my countdown didn't showed up and button got disabled @Raxi

Comment: You aren't refreshing one `<div>`. You're making an ajax request for the content of the same uri again, then letting Jquery mangle that html result and injecting a part of it into your `container3`.

Comment: ok sir but can u please solve this I have been trying for 2 days @Raxi

Comment: You have to read up on some of the basics of what is going on and use your browsers build-in devtools to see **1.** how many http requests your page generates when you open it. **2.** that your jquery `.load` creates 1 new http request, and see what html actually inside that. **3**. what changes actually happen in the dom as a result of that `.load` (and why)

Comment: ok sir... @Raxi

Comment: The problem doesn't lie in the code, it lies in your understanding of the tools you are using (mainly the http request/response concept, and what jquery `.load` does here). Realise that `.load` is a massive patchwerk of lots of generic building blocks stapled together. That one line of code by you triggers a cascade of actions. Making a new http request, parsing and dissassembling the returned html document (doc2), injecting some of doc2's scripts into your document and injecting other parts of doc2 into your document's #container3.

Comment: There are likely thousands of better/easier way of doing what you actually want to do; but there is no information on that here. There's no information on what's on the server side (php ? nodejs ? asp ? just plain html ?) which could likely be a big help; and also no real information on what the project actually wants to achieve. -- Basically, you need to zoom out a little bit.

Comment: ok.... sir.@Raxi

Comment: hey @Raxi I edited my question can u please look up