# how do I reload div with countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have countdown in my container div but when I tried to reload that specific container its reload perfectly but my countdown didn't showed up and also button got disabled..

```js
function refreshDiv() {
  $('#container3').load(window.location.href + " #container3");
}
```

JavaScript

```
var spn = document.getElementById("count");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

var count = 2; // Set count
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

(function countDown() {
  // Display counter and start counting down
  spn.textContent = count;

  // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
  if (count !== 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    count--; // decrease the timer
  } else {
    // Enable the button
    btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}());
```

this is my html code its work properly when I refresh the whole page but when I refresh `#container3` my button got disabled and countdown didn't showed

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <h2>choose product </h2>
    <input type="file" name="inpFile" id="inpFile">

    <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
      <img src="" alt="Image Preview" id="zoom" class="image- 
           preview__image">
      <span class="image-preview__default-text">choose image</span>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2" id="container3">
    <h4 id="title">here</h4>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="main-controls">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="btnCounter" disabled>File <span id="count"></span></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item" onclick="refreshDiv();">Save</button>
```

Comment: `.load()` only resets the element - are you calling `countDown()` after resetting `container3` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this codes work properly when I refresh the whole page but when I refresh particular div my button got disabled and didn't start count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70575762/this-codes-work-properly-when-i-refresh-the-whole-page-but-when-i-refresh-partic)

Comment: Yes I want  countdown on my button after refreshing `container3` div but its goes disable and countdown didn't showed up @Swimmer F please help..

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshDiv() {
count = 2;
timer = null;
countDown();  
}
```

I removed the jquery that reloads #container3 and reset your count and timer and it worked for me in a node.js http-server environment... The component refreshes on clicking save.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <h2>choose product </h2>
    <input type="file" name="inpFile" id="inpFile">

    <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
      <img src="" alt="Image Preview" id="zoom" class="image- 
           preview__image">
      <span class="image-preview__default-text">choose image</span>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2" id="container3">
    <h4 id="title">here</h4>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="main-controls">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="btnCounter" disabled>File <span id="count"></span></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item" onclick="refreshDiv();">Save</button>

<script>
var spn = document.getElementById("count");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

var count = 2; // Set count
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

function countDown() {

  // Display counter and start counting down
  spn.textContent = count;

  // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
  if (count !== 0) {

    console.log(count);
    timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    count--; // decrease the timer
  } else {
    // Enable the button
    btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
};

function refreshDiv() {
count = 2;
timer = null;
countDown();  
}
countDown();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now my `#container3` is not refreshing @ShunnedJeans

Comment: yes my countdown start after click the button but its didn't refresh the div and also I want to button disable @ShunnedJeans

Comment: its work properly but why button didn't disabled after click save button @ShunnedJeans