# countdown timer didn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

[image]
before
[image]
after refreshing countdown didn't showed up and its goes disabled

when I refresh the page my countdown timer works perfectly, but when I refresh only particular div my countdown wont show up and button gets disabled.

note: I useed `disabled` tag to disabled my button

```js
function refreshDiv() {
  $('#container3').load(window.location.href + " #container3 >");
}
```

JavaScript

```
var spn = document.getElementById("count");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

var count = 2; // Set count
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

(function countDown() {
  // Display counter and start counting down
  spn.textContent = count;

  // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
  if (count !== 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    count--; // decrease the timer
  } else {
    // Enable the button
    btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}());
```

this is my html code its work properly when I refresh the whole page but when I refresh `#container3` my button got disabled and countdown didn't showed

```html
  <div class="container2" id="container3">
    <h4 id="title">here</h4>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="main-controls">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button
                    class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  id="btnCounter" disabled
                >
                    File <span id="count"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    
                    <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item" 
            onclick="refreshDiv();">
                        Save here
                    </button>
```

Comment: create a snippet about it

Comment: @Aman Sharma
bro I am new here I don't know how to make that

Comment: please use jsfiddle or codepen to reproduce the bug/issue. Just google any one of them.

Comment: same you are asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70575762/this-codes-work-properly-when-i-refresh-the-whole-page-but-when-i-refresh-partic

Comment: What are the "File" and "Save" buttons supposed to do?

Comment: when I clicked the save button I want to refresh the div and start counting again @ 
Jorge

Comment: And what about the "File" button?

Comment: for dropdown option @ 
Jorge Z

Comment: I've modified your code see my answer and tell me what you think.

Comment: yes I want like this but mine doesn't work when I did my countdown timer didn't showed up and file button got disabled. @Jorge Z

Comment: Look at it again, I made more changes, let me know what you think.

Comment: still showing the same problem and I edited my html code please look @ 
Jorge Z

Comment: leave this code can you do your own method to refresh this div @ 
Jorge Z

Comment: hey @Jorge Z look I uploaded image also

Comment: I got it to reload and restart the countdown when you click on the "Save" button, I don't know what else to do... The countdown timer shows up exactly where you put it, in the dropdown button.

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuu @Jorge Z
brother its working but maybe you refresh the whole page but thank you I tried for 4 days now I find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution but I'm not sure I understand correctly what you're trying to do:

```js
var spn = document.getElementById("count");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnCounter");

var count = 2; // Set count
var timer = null; // For referencing the timer

(function countDown() {
  // Display counter and start counting down
  spn.textContent = count;

  // Run the function again every second if the count is not zero
  if (count !== 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    count--; // decrease the timer
  } else {
    // Enable the button
    btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}());

function refreshDiv() {
  location.reload();
}
```

```html
this is my html code its work properly when I refresh the whole page but when I refresh #container3 my button got disabled and countdown didn't showed

<div class="container2" id="container3">
  <h4 id="title">Title</h4>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="main-controls">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="btnCounter" disabled>
          File <span id="count"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <button id="txt-btn" class="dropdown-item" onclick="refreshDiv();">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```